# Caffeine vs Nicotine addiction

Tags: caffeine, nicotine

We, who love coffee very much, have a belief/satisfaction(could be very wrong) that coffee(which has caffeine) is better than cigarette or any other products which has nicotine. But as far as I know caffeine isn't so good for the body too. Is caffeine is less harmful than nicotine? Is there any comparative analysis on this?

Comment: This wouldn't be a valid comparison so I doubt anyone has done so. They're completely unrelated compounds, and it's not even established that either one is harmful to health. The harm from using tobacco products isn't caused by nicotine; it's caused by all the other things that come with it when it's smoked or chewed. So there's really no way to even answer the question.

Comment: There is preliminary evidence that nicotine may promote tumors of the mouth see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2654098/